# how to alert scrollTop position in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scroll, angularjs-scope, scrolltop

Is there any opotion to alert on `scrollTop` position in **AngularJS** ? `alertme()` works with `ng-init` at the same time `alerscroll()` not working when insert `$(window).scrollTop()` in to the alert

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('divController', function($scope) {
  $scope.alertme = function() {
    alert("normal alert works");
  };
  $scope.alerscroll = function() {
    alert("the position " + $(window).scrollTop());
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='myApp'>
  <div ng-controller="divController">
    <div ng-init="alertme()"></div>
    <div ng-init="alerscroll()"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try using Angular's `$window` (don't forget to inject it) instead of jQuery's `$(window)`.

Comment: `$(window).scrollTop()` works just fine. Please specify the exact problem.

Comment: @hon2a that `scrollTop()` not working in AngularJS

Comment: AngularJS by default includes only "jQueryLite" ([see documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.6/docs/api/ng/function/angular.element)). If you wish to use functions included in the real jQuery, you need to include it before including AngularJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no jQuery libraries included.

Use `window.scrollY` instead of `$(window).scrollTop()`. Or include a jQuery library reference if you want to use it.